# Missing field formatting

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I am having some trouble getting around missing fields in my report designing.

Many of the users on the database have a missing Address Line 2.

The report is being rendered ***using list*** items like this:

```
Name

Address 1

Address 2

Town

Postcode
```

So if Add2 is missing it appears like so:

```
Name

Address1

Town

Postcode
```

Is this possible using lists within Report Builder 3?

*See attached image.*

[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use row visibility to hide rows where the corresponding field is empty or missing.  I don't know whether your data has "" or NULL behind the scenes so this is generic advice.

Here is a great set of examples of the types of formulae you can use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

If the field is NULL you can use the `is nothing` evaluator like 
`=(Fields!Sales.Value is NOTHING)` to return a TRUE or FALSE, alternatively you can do a check of the string length using the function `LEN()` to see how long it is and if it is 0, hide the row.